# AES 128 CTR plain text size not multiple of block size

Tags: encryption, openssl, aes, block-cipher

I [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) that AES 128 CTR mode should work on blocks of 16 bytes (128bit), like CBC mode.

indeed, if I try with openssl to encode 18 bytes plaintext with :

```
max@jarvis:~$ printf 0123456789abcdefgh | openssl enc -e -nopad -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | hd
bad decrypt
140670739715200:error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:425:
00000000  14 f5 fe 74 69 66 f2 92  65 1c 22 88 bb ff 46 09  |...tif..e."...F.|
00000010
max@jarvis:~$ printf 0123456789abcdefgh | openssl enc -e  -nosalt -aes-128-cbc -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | hd
00000000  14 f5 fe 74 69 66 f2 92  65 1c 22 88 bb ff 46 09  |...tif..e."...F.|
00000010  c2 ae b2 99 18 cd 6e ee  55 92 77 d9 e8 f3 1f bf  |......n.U.w.....|
00000020
```

the ciphertext is 16 or 32 bytes, depending on the presence of `-nopad` parameter.

but if I try CTR:

```
max@jarvis:~$ printf 0123456789abcdefgh | openssl enc -e -nopad -nosalt -aes-128-ctr -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | hd
00000000  56 d8 79 e7 db bf 1a 0c  b0 75 9b 3b a9 50 4e 48  |V.y......u.;.PNH|
00000010  3f 8a                                             |?.|
00000012
max@jarvis:~$ printf 0123456789abcdefgh | openssl enc -e  -nosalt -aes-128-ctr -K 00000000000000000000000000000000 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 | hd
00000000  56 d8 79 e7 db bf 1a 0c  b0 75 9b 3b a9 50 4e 48  |V.y......u.;.PNH|
00000010  3f 8a                                             |?.|
00000012
```

the ciphertext is 18 bytes, like plaintext, in each case.

I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTR mode makes a block cipher (like AES) behave as a stream cipher.  The results you are getting are expected - the size of the input data will equal the size of the output data.

CBC operates block by block, which is what mandates a padding scheme.  CTR passes blocks of a counter value to AES, still honoring the block size, but then takes the output block and XORs it with the plaintext.

In your case above, two full 128-bit blocks will have been passed through AES to produce the key stream, but only 128 + 16 bits (18 bytes) of that key stream are used and XORed with your plaintext, producing a ciphertext of equal length.

Answer (score 0):

AES 128 CTR is very much NOT like AES 128 CBC, and the wikipedia page you linked to makes it very clear. Note how the cleartext is injected into the encryption block in the CBC mode, but never passes through the encryption block in the CTR mode.

CTR encryption is done by taking a nonce, a block counter (CTR!), and the key, and encrypting them to make a very-hard-to-guess block of pseudorandom data, called the keystream. The keystream is XOR-ed with the cleartext, to obtain ciphertext. The XOR is done byte-wise, so you can truncate the keystream to match the length of the cleartext. Notice that the cleartext is never subject itself to AES block cipher encryption. The block cipher is used as a one-way function to generate pseudorandom keystream. CTR can be used with a variety of keystream sources, not only with the AES encryption block.

CBC is started, for the first block, by taking the cleartext xor-ed with a random initialization vector (IV), and then actually passing it through the AES block cipher encryption. The ciphertext from the preceding block is used as the new IV for the successor block, i.e. IV is never reused.